# Android Admob-Free set ADMob-ID in capacitor

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am not sure how to set the Admob ID for the capacitor version of the Admobp-free plugin.
The readme of the package refers to `config.xml` / the Cordova way and `config.xml` is not in the cap project? (iOS works fine)

https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free

I'm bit confused overall that the capacitor documentation is so sparse whether I am betting on the right horse here.

The app is currently failing with, add output

```
03-15 22:39:04.536 28476 28476 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 22:39:04.536 28476 28476 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.my.app, PID: 28476
03-15 22:39:04.536 28476 28476 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
03-15 22:39:04.536 28476 28476 E AndroidRuntime: 
03-15 22:39:04.536 28476 28476 E AndroidRuntime: ******************************************************************************
03-15 22:39:04.536 28476 28476 E AndroidRuntime: * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: goo.gl/fQ2neu to *
03-15 22:39:04.536 28476 28476 E AndroidRuntime: * find your app ID.                                                          *
03-15 22:39:04.536 28476 28476 E AndroidRuntime: ******************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [migration](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/cordova/migrating-from-cordova-to-capacitor#migrate-plugins) doc that helps with some of this.

Looks like the plugin is using the `config.xml` to set a `plist` property.

```xml
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="GADApplicationIdentifier">
    <string>YOUR_IOS_ADMOB_APP_ID_AS_FOUND_IN_ADMOB</string>
</config-file>
```

You will need to add this property manually to the `Info.plist` for the iOS project.

```xml
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>YOUR_IOS_ADMOB_APP_ID_AS_FOUND_IN_ADMOB</string>
```

For Android, add this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: YOUR_IOS_ADMOB_APP_ID_AS_FOUND_IN_ADMOB -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="YOUR_IOS_ADMOB_APP_ID_AS_FOUND_IN_ADMOB"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. iOS I had exactly how you write and it works, will try android and check the link.

Comment: I had to add AdMob ID in `PROJECT/android/capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` , not the project manifest. Thanks for helping!